# Tabulated values's management in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance

I have to build a function from tabulated values (two columns) which are written in a text file. The process to make it is the following:

1. Use the command importdata to read the data file

   ```
   Xp = importdata('Xp.dat','\t',1);
   ```
2. Store each column in a variable

   ```
   x = Xp(1:18304,1);
   y = Xp(1:18304,2);
   ```
3. Make a curve fitting with both variables

   ```
   ft = fittype('linearinterp');
   datos.f_Xp = fit(x,y,ft);
   ```

However, when I am profiling the code I have found out that my bottleneck are the built-in functions `fittype.fittype`, `fittype.evaluate`, `cfit.feval`, `ppval` and `cfit.subsref`
which are related to the curve fitting. So I ask myself how I should manage the tabulated values for improving my code.

Comment: Well, there will always be 'bottlenecks', relatively speaking. What are your real timings for `fit(.)` and how much better you believe they should actually be? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to fit 18304 data points to a curve. Also, you're using linearinterp... which means a routine is being run in a piecewise fashion. if you want to make the code faster use less datapoints.

Or perhaps try:

```
ft = fittype('poly1');
```

Not sure is it will be the answer you need as I don't have access to the data

Answer (score 0):

May be "Eval" function could work in your case,
some simple example :

```
A = '1+4'; eval(A)
ans =
     5
P = 'pwd'; eval(P)
ans =
/home/myname
```

and a bit more advanced!

```
for n = 1:12
        eval(['M',int2str(n),' = magic(n)'])
end
```

Also, it has a sister name "feval"
guess, what does it do !
    [V,D] = feval('eig',A)
    [V,D] = eig(A)

and here

```
function plotf(fun,x)
y = feval(fun,x);
plot(x,y)
```

You are right ! all are equivalent,

check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html) and find more relevant function